# How can I make the horizontal scrolling (with bar hidden) and scrolling work with buttons and with out buttons

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

"How can I implement both cursor-based and button-based horizontal scrolling for cards? I'm facing a challenge in understanding how to integrate these two scrolling mechanisms cohesively within my project. My current implementation involves a series of cards arranged horizontally, and the buttons trigger the scrolling animation to reveal the next card. Now, I want users to have the flexibility to achieve the same scrolling using just their cursor. Could someone please provide insights, a potential approach, or even code snippets that can help me achieve this dynamic dual scrolling functionality?

To summarize, I'm seeking guidance on how to combine both button-triggered and cursor-based horizontal scrolling for a series of cards. Your expertise and suggestions would be immensely valuable in helping me accomplish this task effectively. Thank you in advance!"

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from "react";

import ProductCard from "../components/ProductCard";

const products = [

  { _id: 1, name: 'Product 1', imageUrl: 'product1.jpg' },

  { _id: 2, name: 'Product 2', imageUrl: 'product2.jpg' },

  { _id: 3, name: 'Product 3', imageUrl: 'product3.jpg' },

  { _id: 4, name: 'Product 4', imageUrl: 'product4.jpg' },

  { _id: 4, name: 'Product 4', imageUrl: 'product4.jpg' },

  { _id: 4, name: 'Product 4', imageUrl: 'product4.jpg' },

];

const CardContainer = () => {

  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

  const [numberOfColumns, setNumberOfColumns] = useState(4);

  useEffect(() => {

    const handleResize = () => {

      if (window.innerWidth >= 1024) {

        setNumberOfColumns(4); // Large screens

      } else if (window.innerWidth >= 768) {

        setNumberOfColumns(3); // Medium screens

      } else {

        setNumberOfColumns(2); // Small screens

      }

    };

    handleResize();

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);

  }, []);

  const handlePrev = () => {

    setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => Math.max(prevIndex - 1, 0));

  };

  const handleNext = () => {

    setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) =>

      Math.min(prevIndex + 1, products.length - numberOfColumns)

    );

  };

  const showPrevButton = currentIndex > 0;

  const showNextButton = currentIndex < products.length - numberOfColumns;

  return (

    <section className="text-gray-600 body-font mt-32">

          <div className=" px-8 py-8 mx-auto">

            <div className="flex flex-wrap w-full mb-4 flex-col items-center text-center">

              <h1 className="sm:text-3xl text-2xl font-medium title-font mb-2 text-gray-900">

                Hurry! Sale Ends Soon

              </h1>

              <h1 className="flex  text-center">..........</h1>

            </div>

            <div className="relative">

              <div className="grid grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-3 md:grid-cols-4 gap-4 overflow-hidden">

                {showPrevButton && (

                  <button

                    onClick={handlePrev}

                    className="lg:flex items-center justify-center w-12 h-12 bg-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-400 text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-800 absolute left-0 top-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/2 transition-opacity duration-300 ease-in-out opacity-50 lg:opacity-100 z-10"

                    style={{ zIndex: 10 }}

                  >

                    &lt;

                  </button>

                )}

                {products

                  .slice(currentIndex, currentIndex + numberOfColumns)

                  .map((product) => (

                    <ProductCard key={product._id} product={product} />

                  ))}

                {showNextButton && (

                  <button

                    onClick={handleNext}

                    className="lg:flex items-center justify-center w-12 h-12 bg-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-400 text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-800 absolute right-0 top-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/2 transition-opacity duration-300 ease-in-out opacity-50 lg:opacity-100 z-10"

                    style={{ zIndex: 10 }}

                  >

                    &gt;

                  </button>

                )}

              </div>

              <div className="flex items-center justify-center">

                <button

                  className=" px-6 py-2 border border-r2 border-black text-black"

                  onClick={() => router.push("/collection/sale")}

                >

                  View All

                </button>

              </div>

            </div>

          </div>

        </section>

  );

};

export default CardContaine
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCkX6.png)